# How can I read an appSetting from web.config from .tt file (T4 Template)

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-generation, t4

I am attempting to provide a URL in the web.config file that the build system will update before compiling the .tt files on my web project.

The relevant sections from my .tt file are below:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".ts" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Configuration.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" #>

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

<#= RegisterNameSpace("Server.Web.Dashboard.Models.APIRequest") #>
<#= RegisterNameSpace("Server.Web.Dashboard.Models.APIResponse") #>
<#= RegisterNameSpace("Server.Web.Dashboard.Models.APIGeneric") #>
<#= RegisterNameSpace("Server.Data.POCODataObjects") #>

@Injectable()
export class WebServiceCommunicatorService {

    rootUrl : string = '<#= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerServiceURL"] #>';

.....
```

When I try to generate the .ts file from the .tt file I get the following error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       An expression block evaluated as Null
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: objectToConvert
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ToStringHelper.ToStringWithCulture(Object objectToConvert)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingF553823B88CD6076D80EB08F6EA809752D0E5DC3E61C0FA53FB2F9AC22ACABF3B7BB9C8801A54E5DBC2A556C03FA42F2EA2AFCE58B708BEC94B0968193987868.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in webservicecommunicator.service.tt:line 35    Dashboard   webservicecommunicator.service.tt   35
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone down the approach of pretending that the file is an XML file and not a config file. First i find the absolute path to the web.config, and then load it and read the node.

First the dependancies:

```
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Web.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Configuration.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Web.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
```

So here is my attempt:

```
string GetWebServiceUrl() {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string absolutePath = this.Host.ResolvePath("../../../web.config");                
    doc.Load(absolutePath);
    XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ServerServiceURL']");
    return node.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i'm thinking a combination of the 2 answers is probably the right solution?

Comment: Sometimes whatever works is probably the right solution :)

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't access it when I opened it as a config file, due to the access protection level.  But the XmlDocument thing worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx) method to open a hard-coded path (not sure if you can do relative paths). At that point you can use the returned `Configuration` object's own [`AppSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: i've managed to find the web.config's path so far:         string absolutePath = this.Host.ResolvePath("../../../web.config");

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesnt work, I think there is some restriction on the location that it is allowed to look in, and the current directory is in C:\ProgramFiles somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Add the System.Configuration assembly and import it into your template file as demonstrated below. This will allow you to reference the AppSettings using the ConfigurationManager.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>

<#
    var myVariable = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConfigSetting"];

    ... more code here
#>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @AlexRiabov I have updated my answer. Let me know if this is sufficient.